# Why we don't get two tangents in the point form of tangent from a given point to a circle?

Tags: analytic-geometry, circles, tangent-line

In my textbook I have read the point form of representation of tangent from a point $P(x_1,y_1)$ to a circle $x^2 + y^2 + 2gx + 2fy + c = 0$ which is given by 
$$xx_1 + yy_1 + g(x+x_1) + f(y+y_1)+c=0$$
I know that two tangents can be drawn from a point to a circle,but the above equation has only one equation of tangent.

**Why the above equation holds for only one tangent when it should give two equations of tangents?**
(I agree that there might be some inconsistencies in the equation.)

Comment: Is it possible that the point (which is $(x_1,y_1$), I presume) is supposed to be **on** the circle?

Comment: $(x_1,y_1)$ are arbitary external point from which tangent is drawn(it can be anywhere except inside the circle).

Comment: This is the equation of the polar of $P$, which is tangent to the circle iff $P$ is on the circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line that you mentioned is the line defined by the two points at which the tangent lines touch the circle. So, if you want to actually get those two points, compute the intersection between the line and the circle. Then, the tangent lines will be the lines passing through $(x_1,y_1)$ and each of the touching points.

Comment: The slope of the line is $\frac{-x_1}{y_1}$ which is not quadratic so how it can be defined for two tangent points?

Comment: Actually, the slope of the line if $-\frac{y_1+f}{x_1+g}$. And what I wrote was that that line passes through both tangent points. Why should the slope be quadratic then?

Comment: Sorry for mistake in calculating the slope,but how can a line pass through both tangent points?(I suppose you refer tangent point to the touching points on a circle from a pair of two tangents .)It will be better  to me if you add a diagram to your answer.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. If, for instance, $f=g=0$, $c=-1$, and $(x_1,y_1)=(2,0)$, then the circle is the unit circle and the touching points are $\left(\frac12,\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2\right)$. Then the line that you get is the line $x=\frac12$, which passes through both points.

Comment: but $x=\frac{1}{2}$ is not even a tangent,in my previous question the line that I was referring to was tangent line from point P i.e how can a tangent line pass through two tangent points at once?

Comment: Did you actually read what I wrote? I wrote that the line that you mentioned is the line **defined** by the two tangent points. I did **not** claim that it is tangent to the circle.

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is everything clear now?

Comment: Thanks for the help ,after plotting the equations on graph I can see that line is the line defined by two tangent points ,there must be some mistake in the textbook.

Comment: @pranjalverma If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.

Comment: You can also up vote my question if you find it useful.

Comment: Sure. I missed that. Done.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have found in the text should be:-

If $P(x_1, y_1)$ is a point **on** the circle $C: x^2 + y^2 +2gx + 2fy + c = 0$, then the equation of the tangent t**ouching circle C  at P** is
$$xx_1+yy_1+g(x+x_1)+f(y+y_1)+c=0$$

---

If $P(x_0, y_0)$ is external to $C$, the equation(s) of tangents **from P to C** will not be a nice-looking simplified form. However, they can still be derived through the following steps.

1. By midpoint formula, find M, the midpoint of OP.
2. By distance formula, find $R = \dfrac {OP}{2}$.
3. Setup the equation of the new circle (centered at M and radius = R)
4. Solve circle C and .circle M to get $H(x_1, y_1)$ and $K(x_2, y_2)$.
5. Use two-point form to find the equation of $PH$ and $PK$, which are the required tangents.